# PHP Append to a large file

Tags: php, memory, memory-management

I am consistently appending new lines to a 500MB text file through PHP at the moment.

Will this significantly slow down the script at all? Or will it not make any difference?

Any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: fopen/fseek is very light-weight. it's not like php will be scanning all 500 megs each time to find the end of the file. It KNOWS where the end is and can jump there immediately. it'd be slow if you were doing something silly like "insert data after line 34234234234 in the file"

Comment: Put in a timer, then test it out